# Dirichlet's unit theorem in finite characteristic

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I'm looking for a source of the following analog of Dirichlet's unit theorem for finite characteristic fields:

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a finite field and denote $K=\mathbb{F}_p(x)$ to be the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e. functions of the form $\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_nx^n}{\sum_{n=0}^Mb_n x^n}$ where $a_n,b_n\in \mathbb{F}_p$. This is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Here, we have a norm defined by $\Vert \sum_{k=-\infty}^{N}a_kx^k\Vert=p^N$ if $a_N\neq 0$. Let $L$ be a field extension of $K$ of finite rank and let $\sigma_1,\dots \sigma_n:L\rightarrow \bar{K}$ be the embeddings. Denote by $\mathcal{O}_L$ the algebraic integers in $L$, i.e. the elements $t\in L$ which are roots of polynomials with coefficients in $K$. We can look at the $\mathcal{O}_L^*$, the group of units in $\mathcal{O}_L$ and we would like to say something about its rank.

In Dirichlet's unit theorem for number fields over $\mathbb{Q}$, we know that $\mathcal{O}_L^*$ is of rank $r_1+r_2-1$, where $r_1$ is the number of real embeddings and $r_2$ is the number of complex embeddings without conjugates. There are many sources for the case of number fields over $\mathbb{Q}$ but I couldn't find a source for the unit theorem over fields of finite characteristic.

Comment: The "embeddings" $L \to K$ should be $L \to \overline{K}$.  Anyway, there is a unit theorem for all global fields (number fields and function fields over finite fields) called the $S$-unit theorem. It is about the structure of the group of $S$-units: it is finitely generated of rank $|S| - 1$.  If $S$ is the infinite places of a number field, $|S| = r_1 + r_2$.  See Theorem 5.3.10 in Weiss' "Algebraic Number Theory" or the chapter on $S$-units and the $S$-class group in Rosen's "Number Theory in Function Fields", or the theorem in Section 18 of Chapter II in Cassels & Frohlich (using ideles).

Comment: Your MO page mentions that you're in Tel Aviv.  Among the faculty at Tel-Aviv Univ. is  Bary-Soroker, who works in function field arithmetic. If you have questions about number theory in function fields then you could reach out to him.